# Jack was not there...Need to find him!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, knowledge, imgur-maze

If you don't remember me, I am Aidan. I was in search of [Detective Jack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/finding-detective-jack) a few months back. And after a hard fought battle, I reached where he called me. But, unfortunately, when I reached the rendezvous, I didn't find him. Probably, *they* identified his location as well..

I knew, Jack won't just escape the place and would have left some clues for me so that I can track him down. I looked for clues near by but didn't find any thing. I saw a trash can lying there peacefully. As a detective, I have a habit of sneaking into things so I just sneaked in..

Here's the trash can-

[image]

That's all I have.

### **Can you help me track down Jack?**

<sub><sup>(Note-Story is just for adding flavor!)</sup></sub>

Comment: I have to say, this is going to require more intellect than that of a mere mortal to solve this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Full answer:

First:

> The numbers on the trash can are coded in [Tap/Knock Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_code)
> the number on the left is the number of the row and on the right is the column number
>
> I got **"MYTHOLOGY"**

Second:

> I opened the picture and I saw another cipher coded in vigenere
>
>  [image]
>  I applied the key MYTHOLOGY and got:
>  ***"The next step is ieYef.png"***

Third:

> I replaced the imgur link with ieYef and got this link:
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieYef.png
>
>
>  [image]
>
>  **Another puzzle:**
>  The logos of google, Emirates airline, Bank of america, Amazon And State bank of India 
>
>  I noticed that there is a number under every logo so I wrote every name, and took the (n)th letter
> so I took lEfmS

Fourth:

> I got this link:
> "https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEfmS.png"
>
>  [image]

I noticed few things:

> That there is a number on the top right corner like the previous pics,  The lettres are on a Horizontally reflected Microsoft logo, There is a circle around it and an arrow pointing to the right.
> There is a line down the pic, So I guessed that it is a message coded clock wise, but I couldn't decrypt it.
> I tried to decrypt the line and failed, I don't know
> any cipher that relates to Microsoft or reflections.

Thanks to @Techidiot: I've already guessed the correct solution, but he gave me the right way to approach the answer.

> The answer is rotating the coloured squares clock wise
>  then the image will be like this 
>  [image]
>  So the key is Death, and after applying it the line below becomes:
>  Next step is UMUlapng

Fifth:

> So the next link is this:
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMUla.png
>  And the picture:
>  [image]
>    So I searched a lot for ancient letters, I looked at million of pics and finally, I found the one. [Ogham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogham) alphabet the big O that contains the symbols and the rest of the word, Clever :)
>  It Decodes to CVtNMPNG

Sixth:

> Now the pic is:
>  [image]
>  I put the alphabet letters in the blocks...
> starting from A to Z and linking letters with their positions I got.
> vyGdppng

7th:thanks @Sid for the tip:

> So the next pic is this:
>  [image]
>  The dot's are nothing but, anagrammed *PASTEBIN* connecting them and checking the intersecting letters we get - 
>
>  [image]
> So I got C6ndUNaT

Notes:

> 1- Here are the S(start) and E(end) that troubled me in the previous puzzle we must connect the dots between them.
>  2- There are seven highlighted letters, and when connected a forward arrow appear.

8th:

> So the next link is actually a pastebin link:
>  https://pastebin.com/C6ndUNaT
>  there is a lot of zeroes here and the title says Break the bond!
>  So, highlighting the Bond(007) gives -
>  [image]
>  ZCV0APNG

9th:

> so the next pic is:
>  [image]
>  a barcode word repeated a lot exactly 93 times, so I searched for 93 barcode and I got [Code 93](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_93) 
>  Exactly what I needed 
>  and decoding the numbers I got N5Hf5PNG the L stands for Lower case

Last:

> so the next pic is this: 
>  [image]
>  googling the coordinate we got from the beginning 
>  43.765176 11.249987

The solution:

> He is staying at [Pitti Palace](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pitti+Palace/@43.7651532,11.2478194,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x5cd0cce4e6f1502a!8m2!3d43.7651532!4d11.250008)

That was so much fun, thanks @Techidiot for the puzzle I learned a lot  :)

Comment: Now, that you already got the key by guessing, here's what was needed to be done with that square -> [rotating the squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DELyV.png) You can add this explanation to your answer. And, to save you going in an incorrect direction, no, there's no music for the last.

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting and saving me from going in an incorrect direction.

Comment: Does the Capitalised THREE have anything to do with the solution?

Comment: Yes. It has to do with the solution. Start by counting the number of blocks :)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I noticed from the beginning that they are 26 blocks so they may correspond to the 26 letters of alphabet, but couldn't make the connection, I will try harder now :)

Comment: Those *S* and *E* are there for a reason :) Every bit matters in there..Remember it's an imgur maze. All the best

Comment: The letters corresponding to the dots anagram to PASTEBIN.

Comment: We solved this in chat a couple of days ago, if you want any hints just scroll up through the messages. you've done well, there are still a few left though

Comment: Oh, so I will do the writing and give who solved it the credit... sorry for not seeing the chat before. @BeastlyGerbil

Comment: @S.Rafael don't worry not your fault! And plus we know you solved most of this by yourself, whereas in chat it took lots to solve it. You've actually probably done better than we have.

Comment: I refrained from stating that fact as I wanted you to have fun seeking for it. :) I guess, you might have already peeked at the solution. If not, you can stick to your research ;)

Comment: I actually didn't look at the solution yet as I have an exam tomorrow...So, is it okay to stick to my research even if it's already solved?

Comment: Sure. Why not. :) All the best for your exams

Comment: Updated the answer. And accepted! Glad you had fun :)